# Google Maps Javascript v3: Polyline as Image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

is it possible in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 to get a polyline as an Image with blank/white background?

Philipp

Comment: This almost certainly breaks the Terms of Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not per-se, but you can use the Google Maps API to loop through all the points and transform them into screen coordinates. With that, you could draw them into a canvas element, and grab bitmap data from there.

Comment: I used a canvas Element and transformed all my Path (geo) Points to Coordniates on a Canvas Element. Then it was possible to easy draw a path on the Canvas that looks exactly like the path on a google map - but without the map.